# Ping LAN computer with hostname

Tags: 14.04, server, hosts, ip-address

I have setup my LAN and there are a couple of computers connected through a router. Every computer gets their IP address automatically by DHCP running in the router. Each computer has their own unique host-name. I can ping any computer in the LAN by using

```
ping 192.168.0.12  [THIS WORKS!]
```

But ping with hostname does not work

```
ping mycomputer    [THIS DOES NOT WORK]
    ping: unknown host mycomputer
```

I have got one possibility by changing /etc/hosts file with IP address and host-name. I guess, this is not a good solution because I have to define this information to each computer in the network. Please, help me if you guys have better solution.

Comment: Does `ping mycomputer.localdomain` work? Are you running `dnsmasq`? (`pgrep dnsmasq`)

Comment: If you have `avahi` daemon installed (should be by default), you should be able to ping other devices in your local network as `HOSTNAME.local`.

Comment: General idea is around DNS. You can run local DNS server (either on a separate machine or your machine)

Comment: @waltinator No, it did not work. pgrep dnsmasq returns 3335.

Comment: @HaithamA.El-Ghareeb do you think it is good idea to install whole DNS server for that.